# Force Flexbox to wrap after specific item (direction: column)

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a navigation. The individual entries are displayed one below the other with Flexbox (direction: column). If a navigation entry gets the class "seperator" the navigation should break into the next line.

Is it possible to force Flexbox to execute a "wrap"?

[image: the problem]

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.nav .child.seperator {
    force: wrap :P
}
```

I want to have control over the wrap by a specific class of a navigation entry. 
Application example: The first two entries are below each other, the third, fourth and fifth also, but in a new column. The sixth and seventh are also below each other, but in a third column.

Comment: There can be more than one sperator

Comment: No, I do not think so. The **only** thing that can force a wrap in a flex-column is a **defined** height to the column.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feared this answer and consider it a weakness of Flexbox. The developers didn't think about it, in my opinion. For the flex-direction: row mode there are workarounds and possibilities.

Comment: @dotling I have updated the code with `row` and `column` method. kindly check.

Comment: I want the navigation entries to be displayed one below the other and to break them into a new row starting with a specific entry. I think direction: row is not suitable for this?

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve the effect you want by introducing a flex element with a `flex-basis: 100%` and `width: 0`.

Check this post for a detailed breakdown: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav .flex-break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
  <div class="flex-break"></div>
  <!-- This will force the rest into a new column -->
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
  <div>Navigation Entry</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where did this work for you? It doesn't work for me in Firefox or Chrome. You can try running the code snippet above.

Comment: It won't work without a fixed height (in `px`) for the `flex` container.

Comment: Your snippet is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using CSS grid but it would be difficult to make it dynamic in case you will have many seperator.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(20,auto); /*big enough*/
  grid-auto-columns:1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:column; /*column direction*/
  grid-gap:5px;
}

.wrapper > span {
  background:#000;
  padding:5px;
  color:#fff;
}
/*first one*/
.seperator,
.seperator ~ span{
 grid-column:2;
}
/*second one*/
.seperator ~ .seperator,
.seperator ~ .seperator ~ span{
 grid-column:3;
}
/*and so one*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>some text</span>
  <span>some text</span>
  <span>some text</span>
  <span>some text</span>
  <span class="seperator">next</span>
  <span>some text</span>
  <span>some text</span>
  <span class="seperator">next</span>
  <span>some text</span>
  <span>some text</span>
  <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for referring to display: grid! This would work great. Unfortunately I am forced to support the evil IE 11, so display: grid is omitted :(

Comment: `display:grid` method also will not suitable.

Comment: @Saravana it's actually the only working solution ;)

Comment: This is actually the only working solution, I agree. I used this and write a workaround for IE with max-height. Thank you very much @TemaniAfif

Answer (score -1):

I just used `flexbox` method for navigation. `height` used for separator to move the row into next column.

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
}

.item {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:  Using `flex-direction:row`:**

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative; 
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    margin: 5px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 30%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
  <div class="item">Navigation</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the is a row direction not a column direction

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this approach is that the navigation entries break from a certain height and not, as intended, from a certain entry with the class "seperator".

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Both solutions have the problem that control over the wrap is not gained by a specific class of a navigation entry. Application example: The first two entries are below each other, the third, fourth and fifth also, but in a new column. The sixth and seventh are also below each other, but in a third column

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve that using the `flex-wrap` CSS property.

Checkout the MDN documentation for that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap