# How to pull out an element to the right in responsive design?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, css-grid

Here's the layout I'm trying to achieve:

```
       Mobile:                            Desktop:
+-------------------+        +-----------+---------------------+
|         C         |        |     C     |                     |
+-------------------+        +-----------+                     |
|                   |        |     P     |                     |
|                   |        +-----------+                     |
|         V         |        |           |          V          |
|                   |        |           |                     |
|                   |        |           |                     |
+-------------------+        |           |                     |
|         P         |        |           |                     |
+-------------------+        +-----------+---------------------+
         100%                    300px        100% - 300px
```

So if the screen is wide enough (`min-width: 960px`), element `V` is pulled out from between the other two, and moved to the right.

Note that none of the elements (including the outer container) have a fixed, known height. They must all be automatically sized to fit their contents.

The mobile version is also a sensible order for the DOM, so let's use this HTML:

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="V"></div>
  <div class="P"></div>
</div>
```

I first tried to achieve the desktop layout with flexbox:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .C { order: 1; width: 300px; }
  .V { order: 3; }
  .P { order: 2; width: 300px; }
}
```

This takes care of the reordering, but there seems to be [no way to force a wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55742578/14637) between `P` and `V` without setting fixed heights. So the elements remain stacked on top of each other.

I also tried pulling `V` out using a float:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .C { width: 300px; }
  .V { width: calc(100% - 300px); margin-left: 300px; float: right; }
  .P { width: 300px; }
}
```

But then it ends up below `C`. To fix that, I would have to change the DOM order, which I'd rather not do for accessibility reasons.

I could also pull `V` out with absolute positioning:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .outer { position: relative; }
  .C { width: 300px; }
  .V { width: calc(100% - 300px); right: 0; top: 0; }
  .P { width: 300px; }
}
```

The problem with that is that `V` no longer affects the height of the `outer` div, and starts overlapping the content below `outer`.

Finally I considered CSS `grid`, but it would reduce browser compatibility.

Is there a way to create this layout without resorting to ugly hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add more floating:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .C {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
  }
  .V {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    float: right;
  }
  .P {
    width: 300px;
    clear: left; /* clear only left to go under C */
  }
  .outer {
    overflow: auto; /* create a BFC to avoid the float getting outside the container */
  }
}

.outer {
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="C" style="height:50px;background:red"></div>
  <div class="V" style="height:150px;background:blue"></div>
  <div class="P" style="height:60px;background:green"></div>
</div>


<div class="outer">
  <div class="C" style="height:50px;background:red"></div>
  <div class="V" style="height:100px;background:blue"></div>
  <div class="P" style="height:100px;background:green"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="C" style="height:100px;background:red"></div>
  <div class="V" style="height:50px;background:blue"></div>
  <div class="P" style="height:50px;background:green"></div>
</div>
```

Or CSS grid like below:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .V {
    grid-row:span 3;
  }
  .outer {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:300px 1fr;
    align-items:start;
  }
}

.outer {
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="C" style="height:50px;background:red"></div>
  <div class="V" style="height:150px;background:blue"></div>
  <div class="P" style="height:60px;background:green"></div>
</div>


<div class="outer">
  <div class="C" style="height:50px;background:red"></div>
  <div class="V" style="height:100px;background:blue"></div>
  <div class="P" style="height:100px;background:green"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="C" style="height:100px;background:red"></div>
  <div class="V" style="height:50px;background:blue"></div>
  <div class="P" style="height:50px;background:green"></div>
</div>
```